# Evaluating null terminated string

Tags: c++

This is my code, I am trying to simply check if the user does not type in left,right or center (if they don't keep prompting until they do) I swear I have did this before with them typing it in then just using the == to check the string.

Can someone give me pointers(c++ pun) in what is happening?

What it's doing: Even if the user types left, it still enters the while loop to prompt them to type in the correct answer.

```
 void PlaceMarbles(void);

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    char userPosition[10];

    while (true)
    {

        std::cout << "Welcome to the game marbles, please enter: left, right or center" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> userPosition;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        while (userPosition != "left" || userPosition != "right" || userPosition == "center")
        {
            std::cout << "You entered an incorrect answer, please enter: left, right or center" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> userPosition;
            std::cout << std::endl;

            if (userPosition == "left", userPosition == "right", userPosition == "center")
            {
                break;
            }

        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't compare pointers like that. You are comparing memory addresses. You should use `strcmp` or else use `std::string` as opposed to a `char` array.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that's what the cause was but I wasn't sure if it was comparing the memory address or the value in the memory location. 

Thanks Paul.